# Происхождение слова "частушка"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, слово "частушка" происходит от слова "частый" или "часть"? И в любом случае интересно, почему именно от этого слова?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю - от "честить" (вспоминать всякими разными словами). 
"Частый" и "часть" (сами по себе однокоренные) ему родственные, но на очень древнем уровне, корневым чередованием А/Е.

Происходит от прил. частый, далее из праслав. формы *čęstъ, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. частъ, ст.-слав. чѩстъ (др.-греч. πυκνός, δασύς), русск. частый, укр. ча́стий, белор. ча́сты, болг. чест «частый, часто», сербохорв. че̑ст, ж. че́ста, словенск. čẹ́stọ «часто», чешск. častý, словацк. častý, польск. częsty, często, в.-луж. čаstу, н.-луж. сеstу. 
(Фасмер)

Тут оба факта подтвержаются.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, от слова "частый". Ведь слова произносятся часто-часто (быстро-быстро)